# How do I use the verification code to generate a password for icloud server smtp.mail.me.com password

Tags: icloud

Suddenly I began getting a box asking me to enter the password for my Gmail account for the server:  smtp.mail.me.com.  How do I find that out?  The issue seems to be between my Microsoft/Windows Outlook email box and the Gmail box I access on the Google site.

I had a password before, what happened and why?  Now what?

Comment: I will try this.  I don't have a mac account.  I am talking about my gmail on my outlook and if I am accessing my personal email from another computer like a work computer.

Comment: To clarify, I am not using any apps.  And I do not have a MAC.  I am using Outlook from Microsoft on my PC and accessing my Gmail through Google.com,  I believe the issue is with iCloud since the server name is smtp,mail.me, but am not sure, so I reset my passwords for Apple,

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen from time to time. So you have both a Gmail *and* a .me/.mac/icloud (Apple) email address?

If so mail.app (or whatever you are using as a mail client) has gotten confused about what server to use for what account. This should be easy to fix.

1. Open mail.app and select Preferences from the Mail menu
2. Select the Accounts icon at the top of the preferences window
3. On the left is a list of your mail accounts. Select the first one
4. Now select Server settings and see what server is listed at the bottom under Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP).

The latter should correspond to the account you have selected. So if you selected your Gmail account your server should have gmail in the name and **not** me.com. If it does change it to the one in the menu for gmail.

Now if you are using Outlook for email that is similar but not exactly the same. I don't have Outlook set up for Gmail so I can't help you there.

If I have missed something let me know and we'll go from there.

Comment: I don't have a mac account.  I am talking about my gmail accessed from my personal computer on outlook and accessing my personal email from another computer like a work computer via Google.  I understand the server name for icloud is correct:  smtp.mail.me.com.

Comment: I do not see preferences on my computer for my Outlook box, or on the Google site through the internet.  I do not need to fix an issue with an ipad or phone so I do not want to "mess with" the preferences on them.  Could you perhaps direct me to another way?.

Comment: You will need to be specific as to what applications you are using and which one is giving you the error message

Comment: I have an ASUS PC with Windows 10 and Microsoft Office Plus 2016. 
The pop-up box is labeled Internet Email - susan.kay.fair@icloud.com.  I have a Gmail account that is susan.kay.fair@gmail.com.  It is the default account on my Microsoft Office Outlook email box.  I also have an Outlook email account that is susan.k.fair@outlook.com (https://outlook.live.com/mail/?authRedirect=true#/inbox).  I keep getting the pop-up box and don't know what to do.

Comment: While this has to do with an icloud account it is on a Windows PC and I don't have much experience where the two cross over, sorry. Perhaps at the StackExchange Windows support form?

Answer (score 0):

The password is your email password. All you need to do is enter it in.

That is an authenticator for sending out emails.

If you can I'd rather you sign out of that email account on Mac, and then re-add it by selecting Google on the right hand side as an option. It prevents you from having to worry about those things.

Comment: I've tried every password I know.  I will try them all again.  Thank you!

Comment: If your password isnt working, then go to safari and sign in to gmail.com. If your email and password works then you can use that password for it. Otherwise I recommend removing that mail account and then re add it properly.